# How to detect webview redirection process stuck

Tags: android, redirect, webview

I am using `WebView` to open a URL from my app. This URL do redirects on multiple URL's, here `WebView` do job of redirection own. Meanwhile any redirection URL is down or broken or stuck in between.

Is there any callback or any detection mechanism to get know that URL redirection is working or stopped now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah there is just look into `onReceivedError()` method of `WebViewClient` you need to make sure and implement both methods if you're targeting `Marshmallow` or later, follow this for more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. This would include the code where you are configuring the `WebView` (and the `WebViewClient` that you are using for redirects), plus a URL that exhibits the problem.